# Plone REST API: How to clear a datetime field with json?

Tags: rest, datetime, plone

It is Plone site with plone.restapi installed. There is a dx content type with a zope.schema.Datetime field. It is declared in this way:

```
<model xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema">
  <schema>
    <field name="due" type="zope.schema.Datetime">
      <description/>
      <title>due</title>
      <required>False</required>
    </field>
  </schema>
</model>
```

Let's assume the value of the field is any Datetime. But now the value should be unset by a json rest call (Update, Patch). After that call the field should be unset. How does the json call look like?

I have tested some possibilties which were not successful:

```
PATCH {}
PATCH {"due":""}
PATCH {"due":"None"}
PATCH {"due":null}
PUT {}
```

Any hints? Any workaround? Is it an issue?

Comment: It looks like a bug, you should post your issue here: https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/issues

Comment: `PATCH {"due": null}` worked in my case. It's a `schema.Date` field. Do you get any error in the response.

Comment: Plone 4.3.11 (4314), p.restapi 1.0a8: Send a PATCH {"due": null} results in 204 No Content. And when you check the date it is not cleared. GET:  "due": "2017-01-31T09:42:19"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got fixed in plone.restapi 1.3.1: https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#131-2018-03-14